# Slow searching large SQL table on multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, database-performance, large-data

I am looking for better performance when searching a large (>200,000 rows) SQL-server table on multiple columns. The current code generatres a query something like

```
(
SELECT Person._pk 
FROM dbo.R_Person as Person 
WHERE Person._pk > 0 
AND Person.first_name LIKE 'jane%' 
AND Person.last_name LIKE 'morgan%' 
AND Person._pk IN (
    SELECT _pk FROM dbo.R_PersonView12 
)
```

when only one name is searched on this returns promptly, but with searchs on both first and last (often needed to find the correct person, as there will be too many matches on either alone) the runtime becomes unacceptably high. Can anyone suggest a different way to sonstruct this query to improve performance here?

Comment: Do you have indexes on all the columns in the WHERE? Can you look at the query plan to see why it takes ages when you use both name cols? Probably there's a way to adjust the indexing so it can work more efficiently

Answer (score 0):

It's always best to look at the query plan. But you could certainly try this instead:

```
SELECT Person._pk 
FROM dbo.R_Person as Person 
WHERE Person._pk > 0 
AND Person.first_name LIKE 'jane%' 
AND Person.last_name LIKE 'morgan%' 
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.R_PersonView12 V
    WHERE V._pk = Person._pk
)
```

It also looks like you have a view here - that could be the problem also. Post the DDL.

Also what columns have indexes?

Comment: Both of the columns involved here are indexed, I am informed. I don't have direct access to the DB unfortunately, I maintain the software that is generating the queries.  I was wondering if a nested use of IN could force the query to only look at records that passed one search for the second search.

Comment: Seems like your only option is to change the query. Your `IN` example and my `EXISTS` example are logically the same (yes they do limit records begin searched) but `EXISTS` sometimes has a performance advantage over IN because in some cases it can push the search deeper into the view and the IN can't. Are you able to try it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add computed field to Person as NameSurname . and Create index on it.

alter table dbo.R_Person add NameSurname as Name +' '+Surname

```
SELECT Person._pk 
FROM dbo.R_Person as Person 
WHERE Person._pk > 0 
AND Person.NameSurname  LIKE 'jane morgan%' 
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.R_PersonView12 V
    WHERE V._pk = Person._pk
)
```

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by ElectricLlama, views tend to get nasty at times and we still have no idea if this is a simple view or a nested view with multiple ones embedded inside it.

At times when I am stuck with these kinds of problems, I simply try to look at the code of the view, embed its definition with my problematic query and then see the execution plan. Somehow the optimizer is not able to work well with nested views all the times, as I have observed.